# Nuget: dependencies between projects in a solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I can't figure out how to create a package with references to a solution project and a third party assembly

I have a solution with 2 projects, `A` and `B`. `B` references `A`. Also, `B` references `C` which is a dll located in `Solution/libs`

`A` and `B` are supposed to be nuget packages.

I have a `B.nuspec` file which is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>B</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>B</title>
    <authors>me</authors>
    <owners>me</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © me 2016</copyright>
    <references>
      <reference file="C.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
     <file src="..\libs\RMS\C.dll" target="lib"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

I ran the following command:
`nuget pack B.csproj -IncludeReferencedProject`
As it is said in the nuget documentation, nuget will combine information from csproj and nuspec. However...

It gives me a nupkg with `A.dll` and `B.dll` in `\lib\net45` and `C.dll` in `\lib`. Also there's a nuspec file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>B</id>
    <version>1.0.31</version>
    <title>B</title>
    <authors>me</authors>
    <owners>me</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>Copyright © me 2016</copyright>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.2" />
      <dependency id="JetBrains.Annotations" version="9.2.0" />
      <dependency id="morelinq" version="1.4.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <references>
      <reference file="C.dll" />
    </references>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

And when I install the package into a project, none of `A`, `B`, `C` are referenced.

What's wrong with my setup? Is there a way to create a package with dependencies taken from csproj and references specified manually (or maybe there's some hidden convention?)

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?  I'm facing something pretty similar here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796591/nuget-package-referenced-assemblies-are-not-being-included-as-project-referenc

Comment: @pharophy yes, I just added C.dll to lib\net40 in nuspec. The point is that you need to place files in one subfolder in lib... either net45 or net40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open-source Visual Studio add-in called NuProj that does a better job with these scenarios.  It was started by a Microsoft employee, Immo Landwerth.  It defines a custom NuProj project type that you can add to your solution, and does a good job handling references.

You can find more information on the [project website](http://nuproj.net/).