# Create nuget package that references referenced .dlls without using .nuspec

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, .net-5

Problem:  Top level project references MyLibrary nuget which references several vendor.dll files.  Vendor.dll files should be able to be referenced by top level project when MyLibrary nuget package is added to top level project but they are not.

When I run the top level project I receive this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Vendor.A, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Vendor .dll files are not copied to bin folder.

I hope to find a resolution to this problem that does not require me to create a .nuspec file.

Structure of generated MyLibrary nuget package (observed with Nuget package explorer):

```
lib
    net5.0-windows
        Vendor.a.dll
        Vendor.b.dll
    
    net5.0-windows7.0
        MyLibrary.dll
```

I do not understand where `net5.0-windows7.0` comes from. It does not exist in TFM list referenced below.  Also, if `net5.0-windows7.0` is for some reason necessary, why does MyLibrary.dll exist there but not the .dlls it depends on?

Looking at the package from within Visual Studio 2019 it appears as follows (vendor dlls do not appear):

```
Packages
    MyLibrary
        Compile Time Assemblies
            MyLibrary.dll
```

MyLibrary.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.1</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0.3</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\Vendor.*.dll">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Vendor.a">
      <HintPath>VendorLib\Vendor.a.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Vendor.b">
      <HintPath>VendorLib\Vendor.b.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

TopLevel.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MyLibrary" Version="1.0.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[Target Framework Monikers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397501/nuget-references-to-assemblies-in-runtimes-folder-not-added)

[Similar question requiring nuspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796591/nuget-package-referenced-assemblies-are-not-being-included-as-project-referenc)

[Similar question requiring nuspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277715/create-nuget-package-from-dlls)

[Possibly related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also [found an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14553) about this strange behavior and still did not know where the `net5.0-windows7.0` from. Since the issue is still open and **the Team** does not know it is normal or a strange issue, as my opinion, `net5.0-windows7.0` is the special version for wpf project's frameowork of nuget, so you should pack your dlls into such folder of nupkg.

**Although** this is not the best function, but is a workaround now. You can keep tracking the issue to get the explanation from the Product Team.

Or try my suggestions:

function one

**1)** change the `targetframwork` of your nuget project to

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
```

As the Team said, `net5.0-windows` is the same as `net5.0-windows7.0`. However, they treat them differently in terms of packaging into nuget.

function two

**2)** still use `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`.

change this to:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\Vendor.*.dll">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)7.0</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Besides**, when you finish packing nuget project, please [delete nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`, then install the new release version of the nuget package into the main project.

[image]

`vendor` is my custom nuget project name.

Comment: I am not sure I did it right, but when I changed 'net5.0-windows' to 'net5.0-windows7.0' in the TargetFrameworks element, I was not able to get it to compile.  I am not sure, but I think your #2 type will work better for multi-targetted projects.